# Typescript - How to Enforce a Class Method to be Called? (Make a method mandatory)

Tags: typescript

### Goal

I have a `Logger` class

```js
class Logger {
  private logs = [];

  public log = (message: string) => {
    // append `message` to logs
  };

  public complete = () => {
    // log all `logs` to the console
  };
}
```

and **I want to make the `complete` method mandatory**.

Which means that `complete` has to be called at some point. (to be specific it should be the last method that will be called)
An error should be thrown if `complete` will never be called.

### Examples

#### (1)

```js
const l = new Logger();
l.log('start processing');
doSomething();
l.log('processing has been finished');
l.complete();
```

`l.complete()` will be called, everything is fine ✔️

#### (2)

```js
const l = new Logger();
l.log('start processing');
doSomething();
l.log('processing has been finished');
```

`l.complete()` will never be called, thus there should be an error ✖️

#### (3)

```js
const l = new Logger();
l.log('start processing');
doSomething();
l.log('processing has been finished');
if (someVariable) {
  l.complete();
}
```

`l.complete()` might not be called, please throw an error ✖️

#### (4)

```js
const l = new Logger();
l.log('start processing');
doSomething();
l.log('processing has been finished');
if (someVariable) {
  l.complete();
} else {
  l.complete();
}
```

`l.complete()` will definitely be called, everything is fine ✔️

#### (5)

```js
const l = new Logger();
l.log('start processing');
await doSomething();
l.log('processing has been finished');
l.complete();
```

`l.complete()` will be called asynchronously, everything is fine ✔️

Comment: Just to be cleared, you want to call complete(), if error is occurred??

Comment: @AnuradhaMudalige no, an error should be thrown if the `complete` method will never be called

Comment: you want to throw an error if complete() method is not being called for any method of that is being called is it? for ex: 
```const instance = new MyClass();
instance.method1();``` this will generate an error as your expectation??

Comment: @AnuradhaMudalige not for every method, but rather in general. If the `instance` will call `instance.complete()` at some point, everything is ok. But if `instance.complete()` will never be invoked, typescript should throw an error

Comment: I don't think there is a way to ask the compiler to check that a method like this will be definitely called for every new object created. Why do you want to do this? What is the use-case? If you explain [what problem you are really trying to solve by doing this](http://xyproblem.info/) then we can probably suggest a different design.

Comment: @kaya3 You are totally right. I've updated my question with the actual problem

Comment: Reason you want this, I assume to gain the performance. Correct?

Comment: It has been proven that this can't be done, it's called "the halting problem"

Comment: Oh damn, now that you said it, it clicked. @ShamPooSham you're right, that's not possible 

Comment: The halting problem might imply that this can't be done *perfectly*, but it doesn't mean it can't be done *at all*.  See the [`--strictPropertyInitialization`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization) compiler option for a similar feature: warn when a class property has not been initialized.  It isn't perfect, which is why they also introduced [definite assignment assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions).

Comment: Or, possibly even more relevant, the compiler enforces that [subclass](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#inheritance) constructors call `super()`, the halting problem notwithstanding.   Yes, it is the case that you can write a subclass constructor in which `super()` is definitely called but the compiler can't verify it and will give you an error... and you're forced to rewrite the constructor implementation or use `//@ts-ignore` or something.

Comment: @jcalz mh... that's true. so is it possible to "hook" into typescript's validation process to do something similar for my `complete()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the compiler doesn't provide a method to do this.  I haven't seen an exact duplicate of this feature requested before, but it reminds me of a similar one (see [microsoft/TypeScript#21388](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388)) asking to make it so you can mark a class method so that subclass overrides are required to call the superclass method.  The details are different from your question but they both ask the compiler to warn if a certain method is not called in a certain circumstance.  And, as far as I know, there's no way to do either in TypeScript, at least as of TypeScript 3.8. So the answer to your question as asked is "this is not possible".

---

Perhaps a different approach would work?  Instead of requiring that the user of your `Logger` instances call `complete()` as the last method, what if you were to only hand the user a `Logger` instance inside a Promise-like callback, and *you* call `complete()` when the callback is done?  It's the difference between "here's your `Logger`.  Please call `complete()` when you're done" and "tell me what you want to do with your `Logger`, and then I'll call `complete()` when that's done".  Here's a possible implementation:

```
class Logger {

    private constructor() { }
    private logs: string[] = [];    
    public log(message: string) {
        this.logs.push(message)
    };

    private complete() {
        this.logs.forEach(l => console.log(l));
    };

    public static invoke<R>(cb: (logger: Logger) => R): R {
        const logger = new Logger();
        const r = cb(logger);
        if (r instanceof Promise) {
            const t = r.then(x => (logger.complete(), x)) as any as R;
            return t;
        } else {
            logger.complete();
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

So both the `Logger` constructor and the `complete()` methods are private.  The only thing someone can do with `Logger` is call `invoke()` on it, which takes a callback.  There's a bit of a wrinkle in there with dealing with both synchronous and asynchronous callbacks, since I imagine you want synchronous callbacks to be called synchronously.  But in both cases, the callback is called with the private `Logger` instance, and then afterward its `complete()` method is called.

In your examples above, 2 and 3 (and even 4) are now impossible to formulate.  The `complete()` method is going to be called no matter what.  Example 1 looks like this:

```
Logger.invoke(l => {
    l.log('start SYNC processing');
    doSomething();
    l.log('SYNC processing has been finished');
})
```

and example 5 looks like this:

```
Logger.invoke(async l => {
    l.log('start ASYNC processing');
    await doSomething();
    l.log('ASYNC processing has been finished');
});
```

You can verify that they both work (be careful with using The TypeScript Playground because the asynchronous logging might not appear in the Logs pane, but they should appear in your actual console logs).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyD2BzRBTATtA3gWAFB+kOgAc0BLANzABcVph4A7CatAV2GvjQAoBKLNAC+BIqUo06IJBABc0FuUaIA2gF1oAXmjqA3HlGFibAEYgywaNMQ8AtiihhU8xWWUCcuIt+jUAFmQQAHTWwcYQfnYOEE4ofIbC+vheYuRUtPTwtsQgKLT8WAne-oEhMkEAZtwAomDAkSBaAHyZzPC5ZTYgfHxJ3kJJCcZmFgrUNKNuFPAA1igAPABKTTzAJvI81qho8gjI6AKaLYt88ouFKT6tLFZI21rQjCgA7nB36Px9V9fU0Bjaa027zQvSKRDIFWgPAwbhYYEYwBQ8EhAAU0FlAnELt8fAxmL9fto0EF-ChGDwAB7NKFbdBBBjZXL5PgAGmgFJ60EgXMYAE8uTBFl8cYQ0Hk2GhGL5hT4hNAUCAIHRPCKiLTiQycnkUJ8wVcxdQJVK0DL+gk5QZcCJkhU2AjqGQmNAACbwADKWTyAWUBUw1rwe22QSmsx1jSO2LVnR4AHI4Whfm6AJoAOQAwiR0YioG5EDHQZcXe7PSUfQXvCBozHk+nM-BsxBc9A-NyTCgydAKm5An4UM780khPFkoG6SG5jxILyEVZqSqo9ZY-HfgBBGsZ0j16K5gcJMDPMBkX6uj32Us2csLpCxtepjdZ7fKZut9tSruMHt93dWguWv+4IA)

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Wow! This is even better than "throwing and error when it wasn't called" because it can't happen in the first place. You're a really smart person, thank you so much!